# Prepopulate the existing values in the form field in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular-forms

I want to update existing data information using update data form. The input should populate the existing values. How to do that?

As of now, I have to enter all the fields manually to update the form.

Update doctor .ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormArray, FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Doctor } from '../doctor';
import { DoctorService } from '../doctor.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-update-doctor',
  templateUrl: './update-doctor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./update-doctor.component.css']
})
export class UpdateDoctorComponent implements OnInit {



  id:any;
  doctor:Doctor;
  updateForm:FormGroup;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router,private doctorservice: DoctorService,private formbuilder:FormBuilder) {

   }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.doctor = new Doctor();
  }

  updateDoctor(){
    this.doctorservice.updateDoctor( this.doctor)
    .subscribe(data =>{
      console.log(data);
      this.doctor = new Doctor();
      
      window.location.reload();

    })
    this.gotoList();
  }



  onSubmit(){
    this.updateDoctor();
  }



  gotoList() {
    this.router.navigate(['doctor']);
  }
}
```

update doctor .html file

```
<div class="card col-md-4 offset-md-4 mt-3" >
  <h3>Update Doctor</h3>
<div style="width: 100% ;">
  <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="doctorId"> Id</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="doctorId" required [(ngModel)]="doctor.doctorId"  name="doctorId" #doctorId>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="doctorName"> Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="doctorName" value="{{doctor.doctorName}}" required [(ngModel)]="doctor.doctorName" name="doctorName"  #doctorId>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="doctorProfile">Profile</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="doctorProfile" required [(ngModel)]="doctor.doctorProfile" name="doctorProfile">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="doctorSpeciality">Speciality</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="doctorSpeciality" value="{{doctor.doctorSpeciality}}"  required [(ngModel)]="doctor.doctorSpeciality" name="doctorSpeciality">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="doctorQualification">Qualification</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="doctorQualification" value="{{doctor.doctorQualification}}" required [(ngModel)]="doctor.doctorQualification"  name="doctorQualification">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="doctorEmail">Email</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="doctorEmail" value="{{doctor.doctorEmail}}" required [(ngModel)]="doctor.doctorEmail" name="doctorEmail">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="doctorPassword">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="doctorPassword" required [(ngModel)]="doctor.doctorPassword" name="doctorPassword">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>

</div>
```

From this function I am navigating to update doctor form

```
  updateDoctor(){
    this.router.navigate(['update'])
  }
```

service method for update.

```
 updateDoctor(doctor:Object):Observable<Object>{
    return this.http.put(`${this.baseUrl1}`,doctor);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a service to get the existing form data and load the data in the form through `this.doctor` object on load.

Comment: Can you please give one example of service